# How to create list of PackageInfo objects with fake data in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a list of PackageInfo objects. And put inside some fake data to be able use it.

```
val packages = listOf(PackageInfo(
            //<-- put here some dummy data
        ))
```

To be able use it after this like that

```
val package = packageInfoItem.applicationInfo.packageName
```

PackageInfo is an android class

```
public class PackageInfo implements Parcelable {
@RecentlyNonNull
public static final Creator<PackageInfo> CREATOR = null;
public static final int INSTALL_LOCATION_AUTO = 0;
public static final int INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY = 1;
public static final int INSTALL_LOCATION_PREFER_EXTERNAL = 2;
public static final int REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED = 2;
public ActivityInfo[] activities;
public ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
public int baseRevisionCode;
public ConfigurationInfo[] configPreferences;
public FeatureGroupInfo[] featureGroups;
public long firstInstallTime;
public int[] gids;
public int installLocation = 1;
public InstrumentationInfo[] instrumentation;
public boolean isApex;
public long lastUpdateTime;
public String packageName;
public PermissionInfo[] permissions;
public ProviderInfo[] providers;
public ActivityInfo[] receivers;
public FeatureInfo[] reqFeatures;
public String[] requestedPermissions;
public int[] requestedPermissionsFlags;
public ServiceInfo[] services;
public String sharedUserId;
public int sharedUserLabel;
```

}

Comment: Is `packageInfoItem` value from `PackageInfo` plus could you post what PackageInfo class Look like

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu posted. it is android class

Comment: If I understand your question correctly something like `packages.forEach{  /*do something here */ it.applicationInfo.packageName }`

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu I know how to get them out. I need to know how to set them.

Comment: As I see they are function(`packageName`) which is immutable I would rather assign them inside gradle file

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu could you please show the sample?